# Como cambiar el Lenguaje de una KB ya creada

Tags: genexus

He creado una KB con lenguaje "English".

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora que ya cree objetos en ella (Menu, Panels, SDT, etc) quiero cambiarle el lenguaje a Spanish. Cómo puedo cambiar de lenguaje en en tiempo de diseño?

Ya me paré sobre Preferences, y al verificar la propiedad "KB Language" solo me ofrece English.
Quiero cambiarla a Spanish para que por ejemplo las Fechas (Date) se muestren con el formato español.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Las variables que tengo pegadas sobre el objeto Panel son del tipo Date:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

en la Propiedad "Date Format" solamente me ofrece dos opciones para mostrar el año con 2 ó 4 digitos. Pero lo que necesito hacer es que me tome el formato de fecha español dd/mm/yyyy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primero tienes que habilitar los idiomas que vayas a usar.

Eso se hace en la *tool window* KB Explorer, yendo a **Customization** > **Localization** y marcando los objetos Language que quieras incluir.

Luego sí, en la propiedad **KB Language** te van a aparecer todos los que hayas seleccionado.

Answer (score 0):

También es posible cambiar el formato de la fecha en el objeto Language.
O sea, puedes mantener el idioma "English" pero mostrar la fecha en otros formatos.

La propiedad se llama "Date format" y se encuentra documentada aquí: https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?8904,Date+format+property+%28for+Language+Objects%29

Comment: A pesar de haber agregado el lenguaje Español en "Customization/Localization" y luego seleccionar "Español" como Designer Language, las Fechas las sigo viendo sobre el objeto Panel con el el formato ingles mm/dd/yyyy. Lo que deseo es mostrarlas en formato español dd/mm/yyyy. Las variables que pegue sobre el Panel son del tipo Date.  Vi el link que me pasaste pero no me doy cuenta si es una propiedad del Tipo de Dominio Date o es una propiedad de la variable

Answer (score 0):

En KB Explorer ubica 'Customization', expándelo y ubica 'Localization', se encuentra casi hasta abajo, asegúrate de tener marcado 'Spanish', después selecciona el lenguaje 'English' y busca su propiedad (F4) 'Date Format' y cámbiala a 'Spanish', lo mismo para las propiedades ISO Languaje/ISO Country.